# Is Belial immune to anything?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm in hardcore normal about to face Belial. My rapid fire slows enemies 80% and my passive says slowed enemies receive 15% more damage. Are those abilities useless against him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is immune to movement speed abilities only in his second, larger form. Before that form, such abilities will affect him, though at a shorter duration as he is a boss.

Comment: So essentially if I want the biggest bang for the buck through the whole fight I should not equip things that slow him and just go for regular mass damage?

Comment: Ideally yeah. If you're talking about items exclusively though, don't worry too much about that so much as the other stats! (ie 1.3% chance to immobolize on a pair of gloves)

Answer (score 0):

He is not immune to anything, but the duration of effects is greatly reduced.